# UEFI one-time load boot option program implementation

Tags: x86-64, boot, bootloader, uefi

How do utilities like [EasyUEFI](https://www.easyuefi.com/faq/en-US/Set-Unset-One-time-Boot-Entry.html) **programmatically** (what UEFI structs/attributes need to be changed from BootOrderList) implement the "one-time" boot feature? I've been going through the ofiicial UEFI specification and can't seem to find the answer from there.

The feature is that (let's assume I use Windows usually):

1. I can choose to boot ONCE to let's say my USB stick containing Linux Live image.
2. When rebooting, my machine boots to the Linux USB.
3. When I power off the Linux Live USB and boot the PC again, it boots back to Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classically, and as always, I found the answer after 5 minutes of further searching through the spec:

> Otherwise, the boot manager is also required to initiate a boot of the boot option specified by the
>   BootNext variable as the first boot option on the next boot, and only on the next boot. The boot
>   manager removes the BootNext variable before transferring control to the BootNext boot
>   option. After the BootNext boot option is tried, the normal BootOrder list is used. To prevent
>   loops, the boot manager deletes BootNext before transferring control to the preselected boot
>   option.

As the spec mentions, the option to be used once should be put to `BootNext` list